# I'm not able to find a xpath or css locator for this table

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to find a xpath or css locator that will target a specific table on my page. The html is this:

```
<div class="card-help">
  <div class="card-heading">
    <span>AAA</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <table class="summary-table table">...</table>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I use this xpath locator, I'm able to narrow it down to 3 tables on the page:

```
//table[@class='summary-table table']
```

I need to further narrow it down. I need the table for span AAA.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
//div[div/span = 'AAA']/div/table[@class = 'summary-table table']
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```
//table[@class='summary-table table'][ancestor::div[@class='card-help'][//span[.='AAA']]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the shortest form :

```
//span[.="AAA"]/following::table[1]
```

More secure option :

```
//span[.="AAA"]/following::table[@class="summary-table table"][1]
```